# How to setup Stripe Ideal with webtask.io webhook

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I have been trying for 2 days to setup a webhook for ideal payments in Stripe. First id like to test it using Stripe's inbuilt test methods but so far i cant even get a good response.

Can anybody help me out with a example for creating a source that runs webhook -> /charge when source.chargeable? Ive tried a dozen of examples from stripes own docs to all over the internet. Right now as a webhook i have this (which is from the stripe docs):

```
module.exports = function(ctx, req, res) {
  var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_dfgfdgdf");

  const charge = stripe.charges.create({
    amount: 999,
    currency: 'usd',
    description: 'Example charge',
    source: ctx,
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a full example of receiving a webhook with Node(Express) [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/examples/webhook-signing/express.js#L46-L67) — that would be a good place to start, just plug in your API key and webhook secret, then run the app and enter your URL in https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/webhooks.

Once you have the event and parse it, you need to check the event type. If it's `source.chargeable`, then you can call the API to [make the charge](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/ideal#make-a-charge-request-using-the-source). You will most likely need to save information to a local database about the original order when it was submitted, as you will receive the webhook asynchronously some time after the user started the checkout flow. You can look up the saved order to determine any metadata to set on the charge/the Stripe customer object to use, etc. But for now a simple approach would be like this :

```
if(event.type == "source.chargeable"){
  const source = event.data.object;
  const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
    amount: source.amount,
    currency: source.currency,
    source: source.id,
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Ive put it in my webtask an tried to send a source.chargeable to it with a stripe test. First i got 'await is only for async calls' so i removed the line but now it says "Supplied code must return or export a function." ...what should i do?

Comment: Okay.. ive got it to work and reply correctly in Stripes webhooks tester. But now im wondering from where i should call the webhook? Because when i try authorize the payment from my app through ideal the webhook never get called... should i call it from the redirect url? and if so, how? (because i tried that)

Comment: It should be called automatically by Stripe when you authorize the payment. So when you create the iDEAL source, you need to open the `redirect[url]` in the user's browser, which opens a page where they can authorise. When they do that, you will get the `source.chargeable` webhook : https://stripe.com/docs/sources/ideal#customer-action

Comment: I thought that but the hook never gets send... the redirect i have goes back to my app, is that good? should i link it to the webtask url? because then the user goes there instead which seems odd to me.

Comment: the `return_url` for the redirect should go back to your app, yep! Stripe will later make a POST request from their servers to your webtask URL when the source is chargeable. I'd suggest maybe opening a new SO question or writing to Stripe's support(https://support.stripe.com/email) to dig into this some more if you're having trouble.